# How to add Buttons and textView inside the fragment of android libraries places widget

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to achieve like the image below how can i do in fragment android.libraries.places.widget i tried using relative layout but its not showing up inside the places widget can anyone suggest some good source to do it or is there any other layout which can be used to do it.

The Xml which i tried:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Maps.MapsAddress" >


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.
widget.AutocompleteSup   portFragment"/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Chetpet Chennai"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_address">
</TextView>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

Root layout use : Relative

SearchBar layout can use searchview or floating searchview(external libraries)

Device Location can use relative layout so icon place at the start of parent and etc

Saved addresses you can use table layout.

Assign id to the different layout so that you can stack the layout inside of the root-relative layout